# My Java implementation of the Fibonacci algorithm is not working.

Tags: java, fibonacci

I am trying to write a Java program that produces the "nth" Fibonacci number.  What am I doing wrong?!

```
 public class project7 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConsoleReader console = new ConsoleReader(System.in);

        int fold1 = 1;
        int fold2 = 1;


        System.out.println("Enter the number of times you would like to compute:");
        int n = console.readInt();

        for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++ ){

            fold1++;
            fold2++;
        }

        int fnew = fold1 + fold2;
        System.out.println(fnew);

    }
}
```

Comment: Simply put, your algorithm is wrong. At the end of your code, `fnew == 2 * (n+2)` (which is clearly wrong). See if you can figure out why! ;-)

Comment: does it work for n = 3? n = 4? I would suggest using pen+paper to write down each step of your algorithm for small n values and you should quickly figure out the pronblem...

Comment: My output is 8 when three, so not exactly.

Comment: Seriously dude take a look at the definition of the fibonacci sequence and make your brain working. You are just adding the same number each time here..

Comment: i think it would actually be `fnew == 2 * (n+2)` in the end.

Comment: Write "in english" the algorithm for computing Fibonacci numbers .. then compare that to your Java implementation.  WHy are you adding 1 to fold1 and fold2??

Comment: @Gee858eeG Correct, my bad. The for loop iterates `n+1` times and increments both counters in each iteration. With those counters initialized at `1`, they end up at `1 + n+1 == n+2`. Thus, you should be getting `fnew = 10` for `n = 3`. Anyway, the algorithm is still completely wrong. :-P

Comment: @MattiasBuelens true story :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly are u expecting other than just a number ?? 
So first u initialize a console reader to get user input. 
Then you initialize 2 Integers to the Value 1 ...  fold1 and fold2 ... Then you get an input value for int n ... All of that is wonderful.  Then you make n+1 loops incrementing fold1 and fold2 ... ok .. Then u add them in fnew and print the result ... that's what this code does. Say u get an input of 5 ... fold1 is gonna get incremented 6 times starting with 1 so in the six loops (because of <=) it's values will be 2,3,4,5,6,7 ... same for fold2 ... printing fnew to be14

update:

Try this
    int fold1 =0;
    int fold2 =1;
    int n = console.readInt ...

```
for(int i=0; i<n;i++)
{
Fnew = fold1 + fold2;
fold1 = fold2;
fold2 = Fnew;
```

}
System.out.println(Fnew);

Comment: thats the thing it outputs 16 instead of 14

Comment: Try this ... for(int i=1; i<=n ; i++) ... or only use < ... not <=

Comment: After int n = console.readInt();  go for System.out.println(n);    just to confirm u had no wrong input ... This is strange

Comment: Pretty much print all Integers after any assignment / operation ... It will help spot what went wrong ... Tell me at which step results in an unexpected value and the error carries forward

Comment: I updated my answer take a look and please accept if it works